# How can I write code in a plugin for my child theme that will allow me to use remove_action() based on if the current page is the home page?

Tags: plugins, child-theme, homepage

Here is my current plugin code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Site Plugin for this site
Description: Site specific code changes for this site
*/
function remove_sf_actions() {
    remove_action( 'sf_before_content', 'sf_header_widget_region', 10 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_sf_actions' );
?>
```

I have tested this and it removes the *sf_header_widget_region* from each page on the website. What I would like to do now is show *sf_header_widget_region* on the homepage only and remove from all other pages.

I have tried wrapping the line of code in a conditional is_front_page function but it does not seem to work

Comment: Is your homepage a static page or your latest posts?

Comment: My homepage is a static page

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and now it works. I think using *wp-head* instead of *init* was important in the add_action parameter:

```
function remove_sf_header_widget_region() {
    if(!is_front_page()){
    remove_action( 'sf_before_content', 'sf_header_widget_region', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_sf_header_widget_region' );
```

Comment: It's likely that `sf_header_widget_region` hadn't been hooked yet, at `init`. You can't unhook actions before they're hooked.